# In Lombok, what is the difference between @AllArgsConstructor and @RequiredArgsConstructor?

Tags: java, lombok

Lombok offers a variety of annotations for java constructors, including but not limited to `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. What is the difference between these two and when do you use one over the other? I found [this documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) but the verbiage is a little convoluted and I'm having trouble following the basic differences between the two.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In short, use `@AllArgsConstructor`  to generate a constructor for all of your class's fields and use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to generate a constructor for all  class's fields that are marked as **final**.

From the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor),

`@AllArgsConstructor` generates a constructor with 1 parameter for each field in your class.

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` generates a constructor with 1 parameter for each field that requires special handling. All non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared.